# Jquery toggling multiple block of checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have this working, but there is a slight issue...

I have 2 blocks of 3 checkboxes. Group A and Group B

If I select 'all' for Group A then all of the checkboxes state in group A is toggled.

If I then select 'all' for Group B I have to click it twice for Group B checkboxes state to change.

This is the JQuery I'm using:

```
var checked = false;     
$('.all').click(function () {
    e = $(this).attr('name');
    checked = !checked;
    $('input[class=' + e ).prop('checked', checked);
});
```

I've created a fiddle example **http://jsfiddle.net/1kgneajL/**

why do I have to click twice from Group B ?  I plan to add further groups so I need to ensure this isn't going to get worse.  What would happen if I have 10 Groups ?

Any way to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this:

```
var checked = false;
```

both groups are using the same variable... so when you set group A as false, when you click at group B , it'll be false as well.. even with all boxes checked in group B

A quickfix that stores the group check in the group context :

```
    $('.all').click(function () {
        e = $(this).attr('name');

        checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        checked = !checked;
        $(this).attr('checked', checked);

        $('input[class=' + e + ']').prop('checked', checked);
    });
```

no need of `checked` variable anymore

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the global

```
var checked = false;
```

It apply to both group. You should have checkedGroupeA and checkedGroupB.

Comment: So, if you need to create group C, you need to create checkedGroupC variable as well? Not the ideal, the code should be more adaptive.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/1kgneajL/1/) is modified your demo. 
You should store checked state for each group separated.

```
var checked = {A:false, B:false};    
$('.all').click(function () {
    e = $(this).attr('name');
    checked[e] = !checked[e];
    $('.' + e ).prop('checked', checked[e]);
});
```

Comment: Would I need to list each Group in `var checked =` ? So if I had 10 groups that would be quite a long line.

Comment: @Rocket is right, also doesn't work if you create "Group C", "Group D" and so on.. you need to maintain this code as long your app grow, is not the ideal. Check my answer for a code that you don't need to maintain and simply stores each group context in the group object.